# Вынос раздела ВП на поддомен

Tags: wordpress

Возможно ли это в принципе? Конкретно речь идёт о произвольном типе данных.

p.s. плагин wp subdomains не предлагать.

Answer (score 1):

При нормльной настройке сервера, и с учетом, что вы имеете доступ к настройкам, и\или сервер ваш - то да.

Как?

Смотря что стоит Apache или nginx, у каждого свои настройки, каждый нужно настроить по своему.

В принципе нет ничего невозможного, так что дерзайте.

Comment: Т.е. это как бы даже не от ВП и зависит?

Comment: @kossmos а как ты представляешь себе такую конструкцию.

php рвется в системные файлы и работает как web сервер, перенаправляя все по разным адресам, заменяя собой такие службы как DNS, WEB-server, и т.д.  ?? неЮ такого не будет.

поддомен и скрипты - это разные ниши.